# How to automatically activate auditing on Office 365?

Tags: security, powershell, office365, sharepoint

We're testing Office365 and are playing with the settings for reporting/auditing on OneDrive for Business. We need to be able to see who has opened/edited/blah all files as all companies do for reasons.

As far as we can see, we have to manually activate auditing on OneDrive per user by going to

> OneDrive → Cog (Settings) → Site Settings → Site Collection Admin → Site Collection Features → Reporting → **Activate**

Obviously, this will get tedious very quickly when adding many users.

Is there a feature we've missed? The alternative I guess would be to cook up a PowerShell script to change the config en masse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OneDrive for Business is essentially a SharePoint Document Library, so you should be able to leverage the features in SharePoint Online.

See [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2?CTT=5&origin=HA102772739&CorrelationId=cd175ea1-ade7-4e61-887a-a03b9729d846&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) for configuring audit settings for a site collection.

How to enable IRM support in OneDrive ([Link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22861.how-to-enable-irm-support-in-onedrive-pro-formerly-skydrive-for-office-365.aspx)) (Note: Currently unsupported by Microsoft)